# summarise data by group

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table of families and what each member is invited to. The table is sorted whereby the first row is the head of the family. (The summary column is a formula.)

[image]

How could I summarise this data by family, with the events column being a summary of all the events the family is invited to? The events column is alphabetically sorted.
Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Do note that data should preferably be in the [tag:first-normal-form] for anymeaningful analysis in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,scan(,A2:A,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,a+1))),
     map(unique(Σ),lambda(Λ,{textjoin(", ",1,filter(B2:B,Σ=Λ)),join(", ",sort(unique(tocol(split(textjoin(", ",1,filter(C2:C,Σ=Λ)),", ",0)))))})))
```

[image]

Comment: Its time-taking to create formulas *if data is provided via screenshots* since we've to manually type the data from screenshot & then create formulas as well! For future `1` You can easily share test data via this [table generator](https://markdown-convert.com/en/tool/table). Just paste the *data rows/columns* in this generator→press enter→then copy-paste the data here in the question as a table. `2` You can also share a test sheet using this [anonymous blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) & is super recommended